# How do you pass a python variable to my templates HTML file?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am using django and I would like to learn how to pass a variable which had been generated in my python script to my templates html file. The thing is my script is a loop and i am expecting it to update this value after some time however I cannot do this by rendering from ***views.py*** as when i tried rendering and passing it to the html, it kind of just clubbed all of the script's outputs and then rendered the html file placing all of them in that one python variable reference i placed in my html file. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!
This is my loop file which I have so far:

```
def SIVAResponse(audio):
    "speaks audio passed as argument"
    response ="SIVA: " + audio + "\n"
    if 'siva' or 'SIVA' in audio:
        audio = audio.replace("siva", "seeva")
        for line in audio.splitlines():
            os.system("say " + audio)

    else:
        for line in audio.splitlines():
            os.system("say " + audio)

def assistant(command):
    "if statements for executing commands"

    if 'end' in command:
        SIVAResponse("Have a nice day bro.")
        sys.exit()

    elif 'hello' in command:
        day_time = int(strftime('%H'))
        if day_time < 12:
            SIVAResponse('Hello Sir. Good morning')
        elif 12 <= day_time < 18:
            SIVAResponse('Hello Sir. Good afternoon')
        else:
            SIVAResponse('Hello Sir. Good evening')
    else:
        myCommand()

    SIVAResponse('Hi sup bro, My name is siva,what can i do for you?')

while True:
    myCommand()
```

This is how my views.py looks:

```
def LoadSivaGUI(request):
    return render(request, 'SIVA/sivaGUI.html')


def StartAIbutton(request):

    run([sys.executable,"the path to my loop file"],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
    return render(request, 'SIVA/sivaGUI.html')
```

Comment: Why are you calling your own python script as an external executable? Invoke `assistant` directly from the view. Also there is no reason to run it in a loop. There is no loop here: user - requests, assistant - responses. Your assistant does not seem to keep any state. I guess you're doing it for yourself so there is no reason do discuss how it would work for someone remote and in case of multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

you can use in views.py before return the template page:

```
import sched, time
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
def do_something(sc): 
    print "Doing stuff..."
    # do your stuff
    s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (sc,))

s.enter(60, 1, do_something, (s,))
s.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

With Function-based views, the easiest would be to add the information you need in the Return via a Dictionary like this:

```
def LoadSivaGUI(request):
    your_data = some_function_to_get_your_data()
    return render(request, 'SIVA/sivaGUI.html' {'my_data': your_data})
```

Comment: dont i need to import my function into views.py?

Comment: Yes, if the function  some_function_to_get_your_data() does not live within the views.py, you'd need to import it.